# Harpy Archer attack calculation

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

According to what I am seeing the [Harpy Archer, 7th-Level Fighter](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/harpy.htm) should have a +21 to attack with the composite bow not a +22:

\begin{array}{rrl}
&+1 & \mbox{from the bow being magic/masterwork} \\
&+1 & \mbox{from weapon focus} \\
&+5 & \mbox{from dexterity score} \\
&+14 & \mbox{from BAB} \\ \hline
= & +21 & \mbox{total to attack with the composite bow} \\
\end{array}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

+1 competence bonus from Lesser Bracers of Archery, listed in "Possessions" down the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Khaldhool if it makes you feel better, I read the entry four times before I spotted it :-)